# How do I parse this JSON Response from OxfordDictionaries api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

How do I parse this JSON Response from OxfordDictionaries api?
I've did it like this but the data I recieved on the object was null.

This is my JSONWord class

```
public class JSONWord : Connection
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Word { get; set; }

    /// <summary>

    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("etymologies")]
    public string Etymology { get; set; }

    /// <summary>

    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("examples")]
    public string Usage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("definitions")]
    public string Defenitions { get; set; } //Todo.

 }
```

This is my code to parse the json data

```
     HttpWebRequest req = null;
    string PrimeUrl = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/";
    string uri = PrimeUrl + "robot";
    req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    //These are not network credentials, just custom headers
    req.Headers.Add("app_id", "72536848");
    req.Headers.Add("app_key", "0b4ed44eefafe108f88341a4e5cc42ec");
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    req.Accept = "application/json";
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();   
    JSONWord jsonw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONWord>(responseData);
```

I'm getting the json string on the responseData variable but not getting the data parsed on the JSONWord object. What might be the error?

EDIT
This is the json string I'm recieving

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "provider": "Oxford University Press"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "robot",
            "language": "en",
            "lexicalEntries": [
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "etymologies": [
                                "1920s: from Czech, from robota ‘forced labour’. The term was coined in K. Čapek's play R.U.R ‘Rossum's Universal Robots’ (1920)"
                            ],
                            "grammaticalFeatures": [
                                {
                                    "text": "Singular",
                                    "type": "Number"
                                }
                            ],
                            "homographNumber": "000",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "(especially in science fiction) a machine resembling a human being and able to replicate certain human movements and functions automatically"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "a sci-fi movie about time-travelling killer robots"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "the robot closed the door behind us"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0877780.011",
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "a machine capable of carrying out a complex series of actions automatically, especially one programmable by a computer"
                                            ],
                                            "domains": [
                                                "Electronics"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "a robot arm"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "text": "half of all American robots are making cars or trucks"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0877780.008"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "a person who behaves in a mechanical or unemotional manner"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "public servants are not expected to be mindless robots"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus0877780.012"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "crossReferenceMarkers": [
                                        "another term for crawler"
                                    ],
                                    "crossReferences": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "crawler",
                                            "text": "crawler",
                                            "type": "another term for"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "domains": [
                                        "Computing"
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0877780.014"
                                },
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "a set of automatic traffic lights"
                                    ],
                                    "domains": [
                                        "Motoring"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "waiting at a robot I caught the eye of a young woman"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0877780.016",
                                    "regions": [
                                        "South African"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Noun",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/robot_gb_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "British English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "ˈrəʊbɒt"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "robot"
                }
            ],
            "type": "headword",
            "word": "robot"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you should share the json string from responsedata so that its easy for everyone

Comment: shared the responsedata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model class does not match with the json structure, try using this model class (generated using https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
public partial class JSONWord
{
    [JsonProperty("metadata")]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public Result[] Results { get; set; }
}

public partial class Metadata
{
    [JsonProperty("provider")]
    public string Provider { get; set; }
}

public partial class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lexicalEntries")]
    public LexicalEntry[] LexicalEntries { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("word")]
    public string Word { get; set; }
}

public partial class LexicalEntry
{
    [JsonProperty("entries")]
    public Entry[] Entries { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lexicalCategory")]
    public string LexicalCategory { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pronunciations")]
    public Pronunciation[] Pronunciations { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public partial class Entry
{
    [JsonProperty("etymologies")]
    public string[] Etymologies { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("grammaticalFeatures")]
    public GrammaticalFeature[] GrammaticalFeatures { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("homographNumber")]
    public string HomographNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("senses")]
    public Sense[] Senses { get; set; }
}

public partial class GrammaticalFeature
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public partial class Sense
{
    [JsonProperty("definitions")]
    public string[] Definitions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("examples")]
    public Example[] Examples { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subsenses")]
    public Subsense[] Subsenses { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("crossReferenceMarkers")]
    public string[] CrossReferenceMarkers { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("crossReferences")]
    public CrossReference[] CrossReferences { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("domains")]
    public string[] Domains { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("regions")]
    public string[] Regions { get; set; }
}

public partial class CrossReference
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public partial class Example
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public partial class Subsense
{
    [JsonProperty("definitions")]
    public string[] Definitions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("domains")]
    public string[] Domains { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("examples")]
    public Example[] Examples { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class Pronunciation
{
    [JsonProperty("audioFile")]
    public string AudioFile { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dialects")]
    public string[] Dialects { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneticNotation")]
    public string PhoneticNotation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneticSpelling")]
    public string PhoneticSpelling { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how do I use the classname? I see all these are partial classes, so how can i use a main class for this to create an object?

Comment: `partial` part is not required, you can remove the partial keyword and delete unwanted properties or classes, keep only the fields you wanted, but do not change the structure/locations.. it'll work.

Comment: thanks a lot, so if I remove the keyword partial there would be many classes inside it right? so can I make it all into a single class?